# Micro SD card not saving changes (but is not in read-only mode)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, formatting, iso-image, sd-card

I have a Micro SD card here which I used with a Raspberry Pi, and I wanted to re-ISO it with a newly downloaded ISO from raspberry.org.

This is on Windows 7 Pro

In the Computer Management / Disk Management I see the card formatted as it was initially: 56 MB FAT, 3 GB ext4, 11.68 unallocated. It's a 16GB card, class 10 has HC I and an U with a 1 in it.

When I start Paragon's Linux File Systems for Windows I can browse the ext4-Partition and open it in Windows Explorer.

In Windows Explorer I also have access the 56 MB FAT partition.

I can create new files on that SD card, no error is thrown. Both on the FAT partition as well as the ext4 partition, thanks to "Linux File Systems for Windows".

When I take the card out of the reader and re-insert it, the new files are gone.

I have flashed `2018-06-27-raspbian-stretch-lite.img` via Rufus as well as via Win32DiskImager. When I use a USB 3 reader, it writes the image at 60 Mb/s, with a normal USB 2 reader at 16 or so (can't remember, but below 20, it is a a reasonable value for USB 2, maybe even just 7).

On each of this flashings I receive a "Write successful" or "OK" message, and I was also able to see the USB reader's LED flash during the entire time.

Yet whenever I take the card out and reinsert it, it has all the original data on it, same partitions, same everything.

I also have deactivated Paragon's driver during flashing, to make sure it is not interfering.

I cannot format the FAT partition "Windows was unable to complete the format" and in the Disk Management Snap-In I cannot delete the ext4 volume (no message is shown)

This kind of stuff has never happened to me, so I'm at a loss. Any idea about what could be going on here?

`diskpart` shows the following result

```
DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

Using `diskpart` to `clean` the card also does not work

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.

DISKPART> list disks

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601

DISK        - Display a list of disks. For example, LIST DISK.
PARTITION   - Display a list of partitions on the selected disk.
              For example, LIST PARTITION.
VOLUME      - Display a list of volumes. For example, LIST VOLUME.
VDISK       - Displays a list of virtual disks.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB      0 B
  ...
  Disk 10   Online           14 GB    11 GB

DISKPART> select disk 10

Disk 10 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             56 MB  4096 KB
  Partition 0    Primary           3065 MB    60 MB

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...
```

I can even see the LED flashing once when I press `enter` on the `clean` command.

---

Modifying contents of other cards (ie from another Raspberry Pi) does save the changes on that card, so it's not the system per se.

Maybe it's

> Consumer SD cards can enter hardware read-only mode to save your data.

as mentioned in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191393

But I really wonder why I don't get any errors when writing to it.

It's this card: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0081WLJ7C

That card is rated at 20 MB/s and I just re-checked the write speed with Win32 Disk Imager, which effectively states 60 MB/s (a capital B). So probably the card is just damaged somehow.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the disk using diskpart? This destroys all partitioning, allowing you to repartition and format it. All your files will be lost.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I get a `DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.`, yet absolutely nothing has happened to the contents.

Comment: It might not be read-only as far as your OS is concerned, but this is a common failure mode of SD cards. It definitely is read-only internally.

Comment: My normal failure mode has always been the one where the card would simply not show up anymore, with me being unable to access any data on it :(